# How to Pre-Share your Key for WiFi password protected connections

Tags: wifi, wireless-adapter

I can't connect to my wifi hotspot even though I see it on the wifi list of available spots:

My brand new Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian OS install was first booted up today.  Then I plugged in a USB2 wifi adapter, and it finds all the wifi hotspots just fine, including the one I want to connect to, which is protected with a password.  But after selecting my wifi router, I enter my password at the popup prompt "Pre Shared Key" and NOTHING happens.  There is no feedback or error message, and I get no connection to that wifi.  (I've got a laptop and a desktop, with Ubuntu and Kubuntu, both connected to that wifi with success).

The only thing I can figure is that I haven't Pre Shared my Key.  How do that ... or, how do I throubleshoot to find out why I can see my wifi hotspot, but I can't connect to it, even though I know the password.

I searched and found a troubleshooting procedure for Pi2, and this is the information collected from the terminal in Raspbian OS.

running `lsusb` shows that I have a `Ralink Technology Corp` connected

running `lsmod` shows that I have `1> mac80211 (size 542174)` and `cfg80211 (size 420690)`

running `ifconfig -a` shows that I have a `wlan0` section

When I hover over the wifi icon to connect to a wifi hotspot, it says `wlan0: Not Associated` (even after clicking the icon and selecting my wifi hotspot from among those found, and then entering my password into the Pre Shared Key popup dialog that then pops up)  -- How do I associate my wlan0 to my wifi hotspot and Pre-Share my Key?

I need assistance troubleshooting the problem, then associating my wlan0 to my wifi hotspot, and possibly pre sharing my key if it has to be entered into a pre shared key configuration file that I'm not aware of.

The bottom line is that my hardware, adapter and wifi all seem to be functioning, I just can't connect for some reason even though I'm positive I've got the password correct.

-- UPDATE 2/20/2016 --
I purchased yet another inexpensive wireless adapter, this one based on the Realtek RTL8188CUS chipset.  The online reviews I read said that it would work out of the box, plug-n-go with linux.

It's still the same situation for me, I cannot connect to the wifi router.  All these adapters can see the available wifi spots, but when I key in my password, nothing happens.  So, I still have no wifi with my Raspberry Pi 2.

I believe it's not a wifi adapter issue at all now.  It's also not a password problem.  And, there's nothing out of the ordinary going on with the wifi router, since I can connect to it with Ubuntu on a wifi laptop, and Kubuntu on a wifi desktop. (both using their own built in wifi adapters)

So, I believe the most likely cause is in the Rasbian (Debian-Jessie) software, or if that's not it, some rare hardware malfunction peculiar to my unit.

Comment: It looks like you don't know the key (or it is using some strange character). You can try entering the key manually - see an example in http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697

Comment: I'm using a keyboard to enter my password into the "Pre Shared Key" popup dialog, it's the password I used to connect this Ubuntu laptop Im using now, and a Kubuntu desktop Ive used.  So, the Pre Shared Key is something different that I need in addition to the password?  Is this something every new Raspberry Pi 2 will have to setup before wifi use?  It's a bit confusing.

Comment: Also, since after entering my password to the wifi hotspot and clicking [OK] I get zero feedback saying that the password is right (or wrong) and the system appears to do nothing, except the popup dialog for Pre Shared Key disappears.  Is it likely that the popup isn't sending the password to the wifi hotspot router? Im thinking the popup is dead.

Comment: Wondering if you've ever found an answer to this; I am experiencing the same problem, but at work only. At home, I can connect, but at work I cannot. And it's not the password that's the problem; it's behaving the exact same way as you describe.

Comment: Benjamin, I switched from Raspbian to Ubuntu Mate and connected to my wifi on the first try, no problems whatsoever.

Answer (score -2):

Go to etc/wpa_supplicant directory , open terminal, 
type sudo chmod +x  wpa_supplicant.conf
type sudo nano wpa_supplicant.conf

on the editor change line wep_key0="your_shared_key" to wep_key0=your_shared_key (remove quotes)

reboot

wifi will work

Comment: `chmod +x wpa_supplicant.conf` is a bad idea, same goes for removing quotes, please read `man wpa_supplicant.conf`

Comment: `+x` is not necessarily bad, lol, **it's just totally pointless.**  Go read `man chmod` as well.  I dunno if removing the quotes is bad, but it is at least **also pointless** since it works perfectly well with them there.

Comment: string outside double quotes can break if contains whitespace or special chars https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919889/is-there-a-standard-that-defines-what-is-a-valid-ssid-and-password